# Magento URL-safe parameter

Tags: url, url-key, parameter

I want to transmit a *token* as URL-Parameter.

- Is it safe to just encrypt the token like in Version 1?
- Or needs the token to be encoded like in Version 2 because of unsafe characters?

  ```
  $token = Mage::helper('core')->encrypt('123');

  //1) encrypted token
  $url = Mage::getUrl('product/index/link', array('key' => $token));

  //2) url encoded token
  $encoded = Mage::helper('core')->urlEncode($token);
  $url = Mage::getUrl('product/index/link', array('key' => $encoded));
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `encrypt`-function may produce unsafe characters like `=` or `+` only the second method with base 64 encoding will be safe.

Use this twoliner:

```
$key = Mage::helper('core')->urlEncode(Mage::helper('core')->encrypt(123));
$url = Mage::getUrl('product/index/link', array('key' => $key));
```